# CSS decrease padding as width of content increases

Tags: html, css

I have a centred `div` that has text in it and has a blurred background. When the width of the text is less than 100%, I would like to have padding (basically just blurred background) of, say, `5em`. If the text is wide enough to wrap, I want the padding to reduce to zero, so wrapping is put off until absolutely necessary. Nothing I have tried with `min/max` or `clamp` has had the desired effect. Is this possible?

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    This should have padding of 5em
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a snippet. This doesn't blur but the background color should show what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of padding, you can add two faux elements inside the flexbox. These elements act as flex items allowing you to specify `flex` and `max-width`:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.outer::before,
.outer::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: 5em;
}

.outer::before,
.outer::after,
.inner {
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    This should have padding of 5em
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding. This text should have no padding.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is some serious CSS jedi stuff. Thanks!